# How to get specific table header text when the id, name or class is different using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I have done is using each(), then I was able to get the table header text. But what i want is the table header text call 4.1 and only the word 4.1, the results are below.

Html table code :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="user_form3">
<div id="clone_table">
        <table style="width: 100%;" id = "D4_1sample">
            <tr class="stablerow_1_1">
                <th class = "column1" style ="width: 5%;" >4.1</th>
                <th class = "column2" style ="width: 45%;" ><input type = "text" class="inputtext" id = "title1" autocomplete="off"></th>
                <th style ="width: 50%;" >Attachment <span id="cancel_btn"></span></th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="stablerow_1_2">
                <th style ="width: 5%;" ><button type="button" name="addsubbtn_1" class = "addsubbtn_1">subtitle</button><span id="deletesub_btn"></span></th>
                <th style ="width: 45%;"><input type = "text" class = "subinputtext" id = "subtitle1_D4_1" autocomplete="off"></th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="stablerow_1_3">
                <td></td>
            <td><textarea class = "txtareatext" name="txtarea_a" id="txtareaD4_1_1_a" cols="50" rows="5" autocomplete="off"></textarea></td>

            <td>

            <div id='upload-formD4_1_1' class = 'upload4_1_1'>
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldD4_1_1">  
                        <!--<tr class="fileNDeletebtn_">  
                        </tr>-->  
                    </table>
                    <div id="fileD4_1_1_1" class = 'uploadfile4_1_1'>
                    <input class='file-inputt1' type='file' id='docD4_1_1_1' name='fileD4_1a[]' onchange="ValidateSingleInput2(this);selectFile2(this);" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"><!---->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="file" class='image4_1_1' name="fileD4_1a[]" id="fileToUploadD4_1a" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" multiple = "multiple" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="button" value="Images" onclick="document.getElementById('fileToUpload4_1a').click();" />
                    <div class = "preview" id="previewD4_1_a"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> Send</a>
</form>
```

Then i was using clone() to clone out the same table, and the running number will increase 1 every time when i click, then the table header which stated 4.1 will have another table and the table header is 4.2, so now i was able to get the whole table header text, but I just want the table header that is stated 4.1 , 4.2... when the submit button is clicked.

So what I did in jQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myform = document.getElementById("user_form3");

        $(myform).find('th:visible').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
        
        var fd = new FormData(myform);
        $.ajax({
            url:"uploadD4_D8.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:fd,
            //dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,   
            success:function(data){ 
                alert(data);
                /*if(data != "")
                {
                    window.location.href = "login.php";
                }*/
                
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) 
            {
                console.log(request.responseText);
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Can anyone help on this? Appreciate it.

Comment: I've read the question several times, I still can't figure out what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe `$("table tr:first-child th:first-child").each()`?

Comment: Erm i have a try on the code that you given it's not want i want, but anyway thanks for the help. @Barmar

Comment: I said I couldn't figure out what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Section ID is extracted. You may want to increment this `section` variable and just patse it in the next element's header and vice versa. Hope this is what you mean.

```js
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myform = document.getElementById("user_form3");

          $(myform).find('th:visible:first').each(function(){
            let section = parseInt($(this).text().split(".")[1]);
            console.log("Section id: ", section);
        });
        
        var fd = new FormData(myform);
        $.ajax({
            url:"uploadD4_D8.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:fd,
            //dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,   
            success:function(data){ 
                alert(data);
                /*if(data != "")
                {
                    window.location.href = "login.php";
                }*/
                
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) 
            {
                //console.log(request.responseText);
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="user_form3">
<div id="clone_table">
        <table style="width: 100%;" id = "D4_1sample">
            <tr class="stablerow_1_1">
                <th class = "column1" style ="width: 5%;" >4.1</th>
                <th class = "column2" style ="width: 45%;" ><input type = "text" class="inputtext" id = "title1" autocomplete="off"></th>
                <th style ="width: 50%;" >Attachment <span id="cancel_btn"></span></th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="stablerow_1_2">
                <th style ="width: 5%;" ><button type="button" name="addsubbtn_1" class = "addsubbtn_1">subtitle</button><span id="deletesub_btn"></span></th>
                <th style ="width: 45%;"><input type = "text" class = "subinputtext" id = "subtitle1_D4_1" autocomplete="off"></th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="stablerow_1_3">
                <td></td>
            <td><textarea class = "txtareatext" name="txtarea_a" id="txtareaD4_1_1_a" cols="50" rows="5" autocomplete="off"></textarea></td>

            <td>

            <div id='upload-formD4_1_1' class = 'upload4_1_1'>
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldD4_1_1">  
                        <!--<tr class="fileNDeletebtn_">  
                        </tr>-->  
                    </table>
                    <div id="fileD4_1_1_1" class = 'uploadfile4_1_1'>
                    <input class='file-inputt1' type='file' id='docD4_1_1_1' name='fileD4_1a[]' onchange="ValidateSingleInput2(this);selectFile2(this);" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"><!---->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="file" class='image4_1_1' name="fileD4_1a[]" id="fileToUploadD4_1a" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" multiple = "multiple" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="button" value="Images" onclick="document.getElementById('fileToUpload4_1a').click();" />
                    <div class = "preview" id="previewD4_1_a"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> Send</a>
</form>
```